# SQL how to calculate relative value for a group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Let's suppose we selling cars, and we would like to know how many cars are sold for each brand.

The data:

```
car_id | brand | sold
----------------------
1      | BMW   | true
2      | BMW   | false
3      | Mazda | true
4      | Mazda | false
5      | Mazda | true
```

The result we would like to get:

```
brand | sold
------------
BMW   | 50%
Mazda | 66%
```

How to do it (in PostgreSQL)?

Comment: Column sold's data type? Also, tag the dbms used. (ANSI SQL has `sold is true` or just `sold`.)

Comment: Type of `sold` column shouldn't matter, `count(*)` works with any type ;)

Comment: Of course sold data type matters: `sold`/`sold is true` if boolean type, or `sold = 'true'` if character type. A bit different.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` and then a combination of `COUNT` divided by a `SUM` of the true or false using a `CASE` statement.

Assuming sold contains strings not actual true or false.

```
SELECT brand, SUM(CASE WHEN sold = 'true' 
                       THEN 1 
                       ELSE 0 
                  END)/COUNT(*) AS Sold
FROM thedata
GROUP BY brand
```

Output

```
brand   Sold
BMW     0.5
Mazda   0.66
```

Or with formatting done at SQL level.

```
SELECT brand, ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN sold = 'true' 
                             THEN 1 
                             ELSE 0 
                        END)/COUNT(*))*100)|| '%' AS Sold
FROM thedata
GROUP BY brand
```

Output

```
brand   Sold
BMW     50%
Mazda   66%
```

Comment: Or... `AVG(CASE WHEN sold = 'true' THEN 1.00 ELSE 0.00 END)`?  *(And your SQLFiddle link appears to be missing...)*

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `SUM()` with a `CASE` on the condition of if the car was sold or not within the `GROUP BY`:

```
Select  brand, 
        Sum(Case When sold = 'true' Then 1.00 Else 0.00 End) / Count(*) As sold
From    carTable
Group By brand
```

With the percentage as a `VARCHAR`:

```
Select  brand, 
        Convert(Varchar, 
            Sum(Case When sold = 'true' Then 1.00 Else 0.00 End) / Count(*)
            * 100) + '%' As sold
From    carTable
Group By brand
```

Comment: You forgot * 100, cast as char and add `%`.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI SQL answer:

```
select brand, count(case when sold then 1 end)*100 / count(*)
from cars
group by brand
```

If you want `50%` instead of just `50`, do:

```
cast(count(case when sold then 1 end)*100 / count(*) as varchar(3)) || '%'
```