# SQL how to calculate relative value for a group with "over" keyword?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Let's suppose we selling cars, and we would like to know how many cars are sold for each brand. How to do it using PostgreSQL and `over` keyword?

The data:

```
car_id | brand | sold
----------------------
1      | BMW   | true
2      | BMW   | false
3      | Mazda | true
4      | Mazda | false
5      | Mazda | true
```

The result we would like to get:

```
brand | sold
------------
BMW   | 50%
Mazda | 66%
```

It is possible to do it with the [following query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842910/sql-how-to-calculate-relative-value-for-a-group):

```
SELECT brand, SUM(CASE WHEN sold = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) AS Sold
FROM thedata
GROUP BY brand
```

But, it seems like it would be also possible to do the same using `over` keyword? If so - how?

Comment: Why are you storing boolean values in a varchar column?

Comment: The type doesn't matter, it could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for window functions.  Personally, I think `avg()` is simpler for this type of query:

```
SELECT brand, AVG(CASE WHEN sold = 'true' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS Sold
FROM thedata
GROUP BY brand;
```

You would use `over` (in this case) if you didn't have a `group by`.  That is, if you wanted the value on each row of the original data.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how `over` works, I can't figure out how to use it to calculate this query :)

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin . . . The best answer to your question uses aggregation; window functions are not appropriate for this problem.